# How to handle unattended mode in custom form components?

Tags: install4j

I finally created my first custom form component and it works like a charm in GUI mode. Now I have to fullfill a requirement that also the silent installation should work. The documentation said to override the `handleUnattended()` method. But there is not mentioned which other methods will be called during the lifecycle of the custom form.

I implemented the validation of the user input inside the `checkComplete()` method and depending on the validation result I set a variable to the installer context and switch to the next screen. Will this method also be called after the `handleUnattended()` method or is this only a method for the GUI mode installation?

And how to get the "user input" from the varfile-file? I suppose to get the variable from the installer context like `context.getVariable("some-input")`. Is it correct?

Thanks in advance
Hardie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During my research I can answer some questions by myself:

1) `checkComplete()` is also called independed of the implementation of `handleUnattended()`

2) vafile arguments are reachable from the installer context

3) with `context.isUnattended()` it is possible to check, whether you have to display an error dialog or exit the installer process.

Please correct me, if there are any missunderstandings.

Comment: Ok, that's fine. But one question left: how can I exit the installation process in unattended mode directly from my component? I didn't found any Util.installationAbort() or something else. If I return false from the checkComplete() method, than the installation waits for the right input but didn't exited and notices the user.

Comment: You have to return false from handleUnattended